# Bought my friend's Samsung S6 but can't restore with new Google account

Tags: samsung, restore

Title pretty much sums it up - I bought my friend's old Samsung S6, did a factory restore but when I try to set up the phone for myself, it won't let me. It says "This device was reset. To Continue, sign in with a Google Account **that was previously synced on this device**".

How do I bypass this and start fresh with a new google account? Do I need them to log into the phone themselves to do something?

Please note I'm planning on using this without a sim card, just as a portable video device.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's a new [Anti-Theft feature](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/03/12/guide-what-is-android-5-1s-antitheft-device-protection-feature-and-how-do-i-use-it/) of Android since 5.1. Your variants:

1. Wait 72 hours and try again.
2. If that didn't help, you should find 5.0 stock ROM, flash it and then upgrade back to Marshmallow or what have been previously there.

P.S. Of course, the fastest way is to cooperate with your friend, log in to his account and then enter the new account :)